# Train and test set are not compatible

Tags: weka

I am trying to use Weka to make decisions using arff files, however when i try to classify i recieve the error "Problem evaluating classifier: Train and test set are not compatible".

This is my weather.arff file

```
@relation weather
@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}
@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

and this is my weather.nominal.classify.arff

```
@relation weather.symbolic
@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}
@attribute humidity {high, normal}
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}
@data
overcast,mild,high,TRUE,?
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attributes are different. In your first file you have
@attribute temperature real
and in your second file you have
@attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}

Same with humidity.  you need to have the attribute definitions completely identical.